# Multithreading with Virtual Server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, multithreading, vmware

I have an ASP.NET MVC app that is hosted on 4 'physical' Microsoft Servers 2008 with 4 different customers. However, I have one fifth virtual server (VMWare) in which I have problems. I am using multi-threading code to process calculations in my app.

I noticed that multi-threading is not working on that virtual server, i.e. process goes sequential, not in parallel like all other installations. given that Virtual server is 12gb RAM and CPU is AMD opteron 6234 2.40 GHz  (4 processors)

Please any ideas will be highly appreciated...

Comment: This question might be better served on ServerFault. Is your VM configured to use multiple physical processors? If not, it'll only use one of the four.

Comment: I don't really know if it is configured to use multiple physical processors. do you have any idea how I can know from inside windows itself.

Comment: Just like any Windows system - you can check through right-clicking on My Computer, or going to device manager, or any number of ways. However, to change the processor config, you'll have to shut down the VM and change the VMWare configuration for that specific VM.

Comment: the above specification are taken from right-clicking on My Computer, it is  AMD opteron 6234 2.40 GHz (4 processors).